# SAPUI5 - How autoResizeColumn(colIndex) example using XML view?

Tags: sapui5

I am looking for a right way to set auto resize column properties. After doing some research I find autoResizeColumn(colIndex) method. I am not able to find any example using autoResizeColumn(colIndex)

Thanks
Nitin

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the **autoResize** on the column in **XML view**, we have one property **autoResizable** in the **sap.ui.table.Column** and you can use that as below,

```
<Table rows="{/rows'}">
    <columns>
        <Column autoResizable="true">
            <!-- your code goes here  -->  
        </Column>
        <Column autoResizable="false"> 
             <!-- Default value is false.
                 your code goes here  -->  
        </Column>
    </columns>
</Table>
```

FYI, see [this.](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Column)

Comment: I tried this but no success. All columns are equally spaced out.

Comment: Can you add the code what you have tried in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `autoResizable` property for the columns only enables the automatical resize of a column on double clicking the resize bar and only works for **sap.ui.table.Column** (see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Column%23constructor).

The table method `autoResizeColumn(colIndex)` which you have found needs to be called in the controller:

```
var aColumns = oTable.getColumns();
for (var i = 0; i < aColumns.length; i++) {
   oTable.autoResizeColumn(i);
}
```

Documentation can be found here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table%23methods/autoResizeColumn but be aware that this method is still experimental